# jquery .addclass()

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have some code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

   var index=5;  
   $("ul li:last").addClass(function(index) {
    console.log(index);  
    return "item-" + index;
   });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
<li>11</li>
<li>12</li>
<li>13</li>
<li>14</li> 
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

And I see the function(index) quite clearly. However I can't figure out what it is doing. I do see when the new list is built the last li has the class of item-0 . I alo tried to set a variable index=5 but I cannot pass it in (hoping to make item-5 not item-0 ) So what is up with the index in function(index) is it a getter a setter or what?

Comment: Why would you ever get `item-5` using a JavaScript (zero-based) index, from a list with only four components?

Comment: David I just set the var index=5 to figure out where the index number was coming from. I just used 5, I could have used 3. I thought index was a setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `index` is the index of selected element in jQuery collection, as your selector selects the :last li and there is only one element that is selected, index is `0`.

```
.addClass( function(index, currentClass) )
```

If you want to modify the classes based on the index you can remove the :last selector:

```
 $("ul li").addClass(function(index) {
    console.log(index);  
    return "item-" + index;
 });
```

Or if you want to select the last element and add the class based on it's *index* you can try:

```
var $lst = $("ul li:last");
var ind = $lst.index();
$lst.addClass('item-'+ind)
```

Note that index is zero-based and the index of first selected element is 0.

Comment: Ah OK I understand now. So in $("li").addClass(function(index)  the collection returns 4 elements 0 thru 3 because the collection of li elements is 4. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

index is an argument in your case, you can't pass it into the function. :last limits to only the last LI. Here's an example without :last, it will give each li a class of `item-n` where `n` is the index.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("ul li").addClass(function(index) {
    console.log(index);  
    return "item-" + index;
   });

});
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin I figured this out from undefined's post

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're trying to do is select the LAST element in a list and give it a class based on how many previous elements there are. So, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var lis = $("ul li");
   $(lis[lis.length-1]).addClass("item-" + (lis.length + 1));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P7gRP/

The reason why your example doesn't work is because only *one* element matches li:last (of course). So, the index of the element currently matched in your case is zero. If you wanted to set *all* the elements to have a class of item-#, then you were on the right track. Like this:

```
$("ul li").addClass(function(index) {
    return "item-" + index;
   });
```

Note that I removed the :last portion.